# Order-issuing neural network?

Tags: language-agnostic, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm interested in writing certain software that uses machine learning, and performs certain actions based on external data.

However I've run into problem (that was always interesting to me) - 
how is it possible to write machine learning software that *issues orders* or *sequences of orders*?

The problem is that as I understand it, neural network gets bunch on inputs, and "recalls" output based on results of previous trainings. Instantly (well, more or less). So I'm not sure how "issuing orders" could fit into that system, especially when actions performed by system affect the system with certain delay. I'm also a bit unsure how is it possible to train this thing.

Examples of such system:
1. First person shooter enemy controller. As I understand it, it is possible to implement neural network controller for the bot that will switch bot behavior strategies(well, assign priorities to them) based on some inputs (probably something like health, ammo, etc). But I don't see a way to make higher-order controller, that could issue sequence of commands like "go there, then turn left". Also, bot's actions will affect variables that control bot's behavior. I.e. shooting reduces ammo, falling from heights reduces health, etc.
2. Automated market trader. It is certainly possible to make system that will try to predict the next market price of something. However, I don't see how is it possible to make system that would issue order to buy something, watch the trend, then sell it back to gain profit/cover up losses.
3. Car driver. Again, (as I understand it) it is possible to make system that will maintain desired movement vector based on position/velocity/torque data and results of previous training. However I don't see a way to make such system (learn to) perform sequence of actions.

I.e. as I understood it, neural net is technically a matrix - you give it input, it produces output. But what about generating sequences of actions that could change environment program operates in?

If such tasks are not entirely suitable for neural networks, what else could be used?

P.S. I understand that the question isn't exactly clear, and I suspect that I'm missing some knowledge. So I'll appreciate some pointers (i.e. books/resources to read, etc).

Comment: You're not sure how "issuing orders" is related to output from the system?

Comment: @Anon.: I'm not sure how to make a system that would learn to to issue sequence of orders, learn to issue order/delayed order upon certain condition, where order may radically change the variables system monitors. Also "order" is instant and discrete. I.e. in case of AI shooter bot, "throw grenade" is "discrete" order, and once grenade is thrown, it is gone. I.e. I'm not sure how to make system that could learn when to throw the grenade while trying to achieve some goal.

Comment: You seem to have fixated on neural networks as the solution to your "problem" (which, incidentally, you haven't really elaborated on). If you're just seeking to learn more about neural networks for curiosities sake, you're probably better off working on simpler tasks and building up, rather than jumping straight to "how would I build a counter-strike bot using neural networks?". Some wikipedia browsing turned up this tutorial: (http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html) which may interest you.

Comment: @Anon.: I'm interested in machine learning in general, not just neural networks. I.e. I know that given start/end car position, it may be possible to "evolve" sequence of car commands(brake/turn, etc) using genetic algorithms. AFAIK, it is possible to evolve robot gait in the same way. The question was how make a system that given current/desired car position could produce sequence of commands dynamically - it isn't a neural network, and it isn't a genetic algorithm. As I understand it, it is fairly close to "make program that can learn how to play and win chess"....

Comment: @Anon.: ... Fortunately, Svante gave example of different approach to the problem (to be more precise - a different point of view), and it MAY be sufficient. With "how much I want" idea it should be possible to greatly simplify things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* try to connect the output neurons to controllers directly, e.g. moving forward, turning, or shooting in the ego shooter, or buying orders for the trader.  However, I think that the best results are gained nowadays when you let the neural net solve one rather specific subproblem, and then let a "normal" program interpret its answer.  For example, you could let the neural net construct a map overlay of "where do I want to be", which the bot then translates into movements.  The neural network for the trader could produce a "how much do I want which paper", which the bot then translates into buying or selling orders.

The decision which subproblem should be solved by a neural network is a very central one for its design.  The important thing is that good solutions can be taught to the neural network.

*Edit:*  Expanding this in the examples:  When the ego shooter bot gets shot, it should not have wanted to be there; when it gets to shoot someone else, it should have wanted to be there more.  When the trader loses money from a paper, it should have wanted it less before; if it gains, it should have wanted it more.  These things can be taught.

Comment: *"where do I want to be"*, *"how much do I want which paper"*: Thanks, this idea will certainly lead me in useful direction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is known as [Reinforcement Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning).  Reinforcement learning is essentially a machine learning algorithm (such as a neural network) coupled with a controller.  It has been used for all of the applications you mention, even to [drive real cars](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/4347506.aspx).